# How can I remove symmetry from an armature?

Tags: armature, bones, pose-mode

I have a model with an armature that I obtained from Turbosquid. As you can see in this screen shot, there are bones for both front legs at each joint.

[image: armature]

I want to move only the right front leg. However, when I try to pose the right leg in pose mode, all movements are mirrored onto the left front leg, and the the bones of the left front leg don't move at all.

[image]

When I try to move the bones of the left leg, they don't affect the position of the leg at all.

[image]

There is no mirror modifier applied, and the x axis symmetry option is unchecked. I can't find anything to indicate how the bones of the right leg are linked to the left in order to unlink them. Can anyone point me in the right direction for this? I'd rather not have to build a whole new armature for this.

File: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ykw7LA0aLLTbxYVrQb23CEBUxrnu2g-0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: hi could you please share your file

Comment: @Ribbit12 just added to the bottom of the post!

Comment: The weights aren't right.  The solution for this isn't particularly easy.  You need to reassign everything on the right side of the model to bones with the .R suffix.  The easiest way to do this would be separate the mesh object into 2 half objects, rename vertex groups on the right side, then rejoin and weld the two sides.  I'm not sure that it's worth the trouble.  This is pretty shoddy work on Turbosquid; if you've done something to the original, leading to these problems, it might be better to revert.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking a look @Nathan I did make some adjustments to the geometry of the legs and used Mesh -> Symmetrize in edit mode to apply the changes to the left side. Do you think that could have been the culprit? Since I only need to move one leg I guess just ditching the armature and making new bones just for the leg is the way to go.

Comment: The easy way to see if your changes were the culprit is to load the original and see if it works.